# Shopify query null

Tags: laravel, authentication, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-storefront-api

https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-php. I have created shopify app using this template. I defined all routes in web.php file. and I try to call post api in my dashboard page. I have established bridge connection also. Issue is that When I call post API. I got shop query null. Here I call API timer_post, error is shop query I got null

[image]
[image]

[image]

> Shopify\Utils::sanitizeShopDomain(): Argument #1 ($shop) must be of type string, null given, called in /app/app/Lib/AuthRedirection.php on line 19 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Shopify\Utils::sanitizeShopDomain(): Argument #1 ($shop) must be of type string, null given, called in /app/app/Lib/AuthRedirection.php on line 19 at /app/vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Utils.php:32)

I tried to change in env file. and do some modification in routes. also check bridge connection but I couldn't get proper solution

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].